# Sublime Text 3 - How to install JSHint

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3, I like this. And I like JSHint that helps us to improve coding standards. Currently I am copying my javascript code to http://jshint.com/ and doing changes, then pasting back to my files.

Please help me to install jshint in Sublime Text 3 friends. Thanks in advance

Comment: from http://jshint.com/install/ . https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint

Comment: in html and js Sublime already showing hit for code completion, not sure what you where asking

Answer (score 7):

The method I followed.

First install sublime package control. https://packagecontrol.io/installation.

Then

- `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P` in Linux/Windows/OS X
- type `install`, select `Package Control: Install Package`
- type `js gutter`, select `JSHint Gutte`

From https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint readme. If you are not interested in installing via package control use other methods listed in the readme.

Comment: sublime package control already there in my sublime Text 3 tkay.

Comment: great. then do the rest . Ctrl+Shift+P , type install, select Package Control: Install Package , type js gutter, select JSHint Gutte.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed. How to run JShint after installation?

Comment: Usage is also listed in the link. Please do some research on your own before asking something. No one is here to do everything. That's not what SO is for.

Comment: Open a JavaScript file, pop out the console in Sublime Text from View -> Show Console, and type `view.run_command("jshint")`. You can set keybindings for this to make it easier to use. Refer the github readme.

Answer (score 0):

Refer these links which tells you how to install jshint and alsi jslint for your sublime text editor.

> [js hint](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint)
>
> [Js hint II](https://github.com/uipoet/sublime-jshint)
>
> [sublime linter](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeLinter)

Also refer this link of the js hint install page

> [JS hint download and install](http://jshint.com/install/)

This page will help you in your future on how to download and install jshint in various editors.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd + Shift + P` Linux/OS X

type & select `Package Control: Install Package`

type & select `JsHint`

or

`npm install -g jshint`(but for this you need to install node and npm)